How to properly set up Thread pool and maxMessagePerPoll in Spring Integration TaskExecutor for File adapter to avoid heap issue
There's 2 issues I keep encountering and don't know how to resolve it.

GC overhead limit exceeded (Out of heap space, application currently using 2gb)
App pauses ThreadPoolExecutor Pool size= 50, active threads = 50, queued task= 50

From my understanding you need 1 thread per message poll. I set taskExecutor pool size to 50 and file adapter to fixed rate of 25 max message per poll. So, how does issue 2) happen if at most it'll use 25 threads out of 50?
I'm also using transaction-manager/sync factory to delete each file after processing. Does this have any impact on the above?

No, the logic there is like this:
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });

So, one thread is used for the whole maxMessagesPerPoll batch. Apparently you have some how too many files to pull from directory. Plus it sounds like the processing for those files is too slow to pile up tasks in that ThreadPoolExecutor.
We need to see more of your configuration and flow logic to determine where exactly those threads are stuck. You can use JConsole to observer those memory leaks and blocked threads.

Hmm it takes 1 second to process each message. But, you are right that I have to process a ton of files. So what you're saying is I should changed the fixed-rate of 1000 to at least 5000? If MQ sends 50 files per second to my directory. With 1000 fixed rate it will use 5 threads (Each thread will process 50 files). If I set fixed rate to 5000, 1 thread will process the batch of 250 files?

Also does using RegexPatternFileListFilter drastically decrease the performance? If used for processing 50k+ files in a short duration? Or should I not give a value to maxmessageperpoll?

You might also look into a fixed-delay instead. Also see if you use AcceptOnceFileListFilter (or similar) to avoid re-processing same file again. Yes, fixed-rate makes it the way that a new concurrent task is scheduled for that maxMessagesPerPoll. Therefore it is not a surprise that all your threads might be taken since currently obtained are busy handling your files.

Are you saying fixed-delay is an alternative for AcceptOnceFileListFilter to avoid re-processing same file again? For fixed-delay I can put 1000 with no issues right since it will just thread.sleep for 1 second after the entire file batch is completed, instead of fixed-rate where it will force a thread to start the next file batch even when the thread hasn't finished the previous batch. If I need to process 60k files per hour. How do I figure out the thread pool size and maxmsgperpoll?

It's all depend on your situation: how big are files? how long do you process them? how much memory you can dedicate to your Java? I suggest fixed-delay to minimize a heap impact since it looks like all those files in the memory for parallel processing are the problem.  You really might not be able to process those 60k files in an hour if they don't fit into those 2gb and are processed too slow. It might be the fact that memory consumption does not come from that ThreadPoolExecutor, but rather somewhere downstream where you open them for processing.
